# Propel ORM: How to save Object only, if such an object doesnt already exist

Tags: propel, exists

I'm using the Propel ORM. One of my tables is called "friend" and its entries represent many-to-many-relationships. The table "friend" has to entries:

- profile_id
- friend_profile_id

These two properties obviously create the PrimaryKey.

Now I would like to update this table, with new Information. So I would like to save new Friend-Entries like so:

```
$friendCon = new RplFriend();
$friendCon->setProfileId($profile->getId());
$friendCon->setFriendProfileId($friendProfile->getId());
$friendCon->save();
```

But at this point, I dont know if such an entry already exists. So I get lots of "Duplicate Entry" errors from Propel. What is the most performant way, to only save a new entry, if it doesnt already exist?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try something like:

```
$friendCon_duplicate = RplFriendQuery::create()->findPK($profile->getId(),$friendProfile->getId());

if($friendCon_duplicate..
```

Answer (score -1):

set unique index of those 2 fields in your database